# Environment variables accessibility using javascript

Tags: javascript

Am working on a program in which 1 of the sub-tasks is to fetch the system environment variable values. I have the flexibility of choosing either Vbscript or Javascript for the entire code. Fetching env variables using VbScript is possible but ideally I would like to go with javascript but after going through several of the posts it appears that the env variables can be read using node.js. I haven't come across any source containing information related to fetching env variables through normal javascript code. 
Was looking to find out if there's any way of fetching the env. variables using javascript without using any external frameworks.

Comment: you can't from a web browser. thats privileged information that the browser sandbox wont let you access.

Comment: Okay but comparatively Vbscript is indeed able to fetch the variables. Any idea why is this possible.. thanks in advance.

Comment: internet explorer allows you to do somethings that are bad.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the flexibility of choosing either Vbscript or Javascript for the entire code. Fetching env variables using VbScript is possible but ideally I would like to go with javascript

Accessing environment variables has nothing to do with the language you write your code in. It's a function of the host environment in which the code runs. You can read environment variables with VBScript or with JScript in a Windows Scripting Host environment, for instance. You can also read environment variables, as you mentioned, from JavaScript code in a Node.js process (using [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)).

JavaScript is closely associated with web browser hosts and their (appropriate) limitations on what you can do in that host environment, but those limitations are nothing to do with the language.

Answer (score 0):

From a browser (if dynamic imports aren't an option) you can serve env variables from somewhere accessible (the root is fine) and load them in as `json` or whatever suits.

If your app is hosted on a Node webserver you can just copy the config in to somewhere accessible and fetch it from there.

There is quite a good overview of your options [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/environment-settings-in-javascript-apps-c5f9744282b6/)